# jOOQ Mocking: Why does insert require me to prepare a MockResult for a subsequent select?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have a jOOQ MockConnection/DSL set up for unit tests to be able to do `insert`, but in at least one instance of my testing I have to also implement a MockResult for a subsequent select statement.

My question is, why does jOOQ execute a select statement in `org.jooq.impl.AbstractDMLQuery#executeReturningGeneratedKeysFetchAdditionalRows` -> `selectReturning` for my insert?

My insert is a simple `myRecord.insert()`, and the mocked DSL looks something like this:

```java
// Simplified
var connection = new MockConnection(ctx -> {
    var sql = ctx.sql();
    if (sql.startsWith("insert")) {
        return mockResultCount(1); // Impl elsewhere
    }
    return null;
});
var dsl = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.MYSQL);

[...]

var myRecord = new MyRecord();
myRecord.setX(...).setY(...);

dsl.attach(myRecord);

// Why does this require a mocked insert result AND a mocked select result?
myRecord.insert();
```

And my test fails because jOOQ needs the DSL to return a result for a select on something like `SELECT ID_COLUMN, UNIQUE_KEY_COLUMN WHERE UNIQUE_KEY_COLUMN = ?`

The only thing I can think of is that this table has a unique key?

Anyone know why a simple `record.insert();` requires a select statement to be executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on a variety of factors.

- First off, the dialect. MySQL, for example cannot fetch values other than the identity values via JDBC's `Statement.getGeneratedKeys()`. This is the main reasons why there might be an additional query at all.
- Then, for example, your [`Settings.returnAllOnUpdatableRecord`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/conf/Settings.html#returnAllOnUpdatableRecord) configuration might cause this behaviour. If you have turned this on, then a separate query is required in MySQL to fetch the non-identity values.
- Or, if your identity column (in MySQL, the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column) does not coincide with your primary key, which seems to be the case given your logged SQL statement, where you distinguish between an `ID_COLUMN` and a `UNIQUE_KEY_COLUMN`.

The reason for this fetching is that jOOQ assumes that such values may be generated (e.g. by triggers). I guess that the special case where

- The identity and the primary key do not coincide
- The primary key has been supplied fully by the user

We can attempt not to fetch the possibly generated primary key value, and fetch only the identity value. I've created a feature request for this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9125